# android studios can´t open other app

Tags: android

Ii have a code to open a calculator from another application, the code working well, but I change the package name to open a different app does not work

Does anyone know what I have to change

```
package com.example.zeluis.c4;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class c4 extends AppCompatActivity {
    // aki comesa abrir os app

    private String packge_name = "com.android.calculator2";
    private String class_name = "com.android.calculator2.Calculator";
    private Button bt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_c4);
        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                launchCall();
            }
        });

    }

    protected void launchCall() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packge_name, class_name));
        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_c4, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

My idea was to change the package name to open another app such as whatapp or Navfree .etc

Comment: I'm not sure what the exact question is, are you saying `launchCall()` isn't working? If so, show what it does.

Comment: You have provided everything but the bit of code we actually need to see...

Comment: now i past the all code. this code work but i whant open other app not the calculator i cant

Comment: What values are you using for `packge_name` (sic) and `class_name` when you try to open a different app?

Comment: private String packge_name = "com.navfree.android.OSM.ALL";
    private String class_name = "com.navfree.android.OSM.ALL.com.navfree.android.OSM.ALL-2";
    private Button bt;

Comment: I try with that name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest is to ask the package manager for the 'launching intent' for a package:

```
private static void launchPackage(Context context, String packageName) {
    Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    try {
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Unknown package, or has no launching activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This way you don't need to know the launcher activity class name. The package manager will look that up in the manifest of the package.

However, if you inspect the intent that it returns, you will see that it is basically the same as what your code builds. So I suspect that you are using the wrong values for packageName and/or className.

You write in a comment that you are testing with `private String class_name = "com.navfree.android.OSM.ALL.com.navfree.android.OSM.ALL-2";` that doesn't look like the class name of an activity to me.